# Admob policy violations under Modified ad code Resizing Ad Frames

Tags: admob, adsense, banner-ads

I got a mail sayin policy viaolations on Modified ad code: Resizing Ad Frames

1st ad

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

2nd ad

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adViewQuestions"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

3rd ad

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adViewBookmarks"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

4th ad

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adViewProgram"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

5th ad

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

6th ad

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

7th ad
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

code used
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
this is how I used... can someone help me what is the issue.

I have a webview which will show static HTML of mine and I'm displaying an ad on it but I don't think it will violate policy

Comment: First of all need to post whole xml layout so one can check but though as per my view there may be issue with layout_weight property banner may hide with the view so i suggest to remove weight or provide sufficient weight so when big size banner displayed your view remain same

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you can (policy) show ads in a webview. I don't believe that is allowed.

Comment: But policy says that ads resizing. And if not webview then how to load html